# Ultimate thread group is not visible though respective plugin was installed

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I installed applicable plugin in the newest version of Jmeter but Ultimate Thread group option is not listed in the thread groups list.

I download and copied the `JMeterPlugins-Standard-1.4.0.jar` file inside `/../lib/ext/` folder of JMeter install on Mac OS. I also installed Plugin manager before copying plugin jar.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Could someone let me know how to get his working?

Comment: Can you check in jmeter.log for some exceptions

Comment: kg.apc.jmeter.JMeterPluginsUtils: JMeter-Plugins.org v.1.4.0  you will see this line if it loaded properly

Comment: Also can you paste the snapshot just to make sure you are looking into the right menu option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I copied all the content of unzipped content to respective 'ext' folder instead of only doing jar files, then I see plugin is working.